# How do I unbind Windows S from conemu?

Tags: conemu

I really like ConEmu, but it captures Windows key + S (search in Win 10) and binds it to "duplicate tab". I've searched all over for where this is set in ConEmu, but I can't find it. How do I turn this feature off, so Windows + S works as it does in other applications?

-- edit --

In response to a comment, this is what I see when looking at settings. I see a number of options related to Win keys, but none specific to Win+S (the only one I want to unbind). Am I missing something obvious?

[image]

Comment: What exactly gave you searched and where?

Comment: I looked through all the settings menu options

Comment: Is there another place that I should be looking?

Comment: **All settings**? Where? Hotkeys are modified in the only place - "Keys & Macro" page.

Comment: I've looked in there, but I only see the ability to install keyboard hooks (or not). There is nothing about particular keyboard hooks/shortcuts. I like having the other Windows + XXX shortcuts, just not Windows + S

Comment: "but I only see the ability to install keyboard hooks". Really??? Show the screenshot.

Comment: I just updated the main post to include the screenshot.

Comment: I've already told you: Hotkeys are modified in the only place - "Keys & Macro" page. But you show the screenshot of page "Keyboard". Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what I was missing. The settings window has a tree view, and I was looking on the Keyboard node under Keys & Macros. It turns out that the most of the keyboard shortcuts can be found by selecting the Keys & Macros node (the parent of Keyboard).

[image: The place I was looking for]